# having hard time showing scroll bar in a nested div with no fixed width or height

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div which is inside another div and none of the elements have fixed width or height. The center div (class:page-detail-left-content) should be flexible as the window size changes, but needs to have a min width and show a scroll bar when appropriate.

Any suggestions?

```css
.page-detail {
  height: 100%;
}

.page-detail-with-filter {
  margin-left: 240px;
}

.page-detail-right {
  float: right;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  background: green;
}

.page-detail-left {
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 240px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.page-detail-left-main-content {
  bottom: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 190px;
  overflow: scroll;
  right: 240px;
  min-width: 800px;
  left: 10px;
}

.page-detail-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
  right: 240px;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -10;
}

.filterSelection {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='filterSelection'>
  <div class='page-detail-right'>
    RIGHT
  </div>
  <div class='page-detail-left'>
    <div style="height:100%;">
      <div style="height:80px;">
        header
      </div>
      <div style="border-top:1px solid; border-bottom:1px solid;height:50px;" class="gray2">
        header2
      </div>
      <div class="page-detail-left-main-content">
        dskhfjkajf ajsdhfjk asdfhah sdfha sdfhaskdhf kjahsdjkfh ajsdhf asdkjfhakjsdh fkjh askdj fhjaksdhfj ahsdjfkh asjkfhdajskh fdjkhsdf sdfjkasdfh ajkdhfjka hdjkhafkjsh kjfhashdkfj hsjdhf hdsfak jhdfa shdfajkhsdf adhf akdsjhfkajhd sfkjahsdkjf haksjdhfasdf adf
        dsfjadjkfhak sdhfkjashdfjk adhfa hdfh
      </div>
      <div class="page-detail-bottom">
        bottom bar
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you considered using flexboxes? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

**Can you try replacing your CSS with this?** It uses @media queries, which define conditional rules in CSS. In this case, `.page-detail-left-main-content` will be given `overflow: scroll` when the window's width is less than 1000px.

```css
.page-detail {
  height: 100%;
}

.page-detail-with-filter {
  margin-left: 240px;
}

.page-detail-right {
  float: right;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  background: green;
}

.page-detail-left {
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 240px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.page-detail-left-main-content {
  bottom: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 190px;
  right: 240px;
  min-width: 800px;
  left: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .page-detail-left-main-content {
    overflow: scroll;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class='filterSelection'>
  <div class='page-detail-right'>
    RIGHT
  </div>
  <div class='page-detail-left'>
    <div style="height:100%;">
      <div style="height:80px;">
        header
      </div>
      <div style="border-top:1px solid; border-bottom:1px solid;height:50px;" class="gray2">
        header2
      </div>
      <div class="page-detail-left-main-content">
        dskhfjkajf ajsdhfjk asdfhah sdfha sdfhaskdhf kjahsdjkfh ajsdhf asdkjfhakjsdh fkjh askdj fhjaksdhfj ahsdjfkh asjkfhdajskh fdjkhsdf sdfjkasdfh ajkdhfjka hdjkhafkjsh kjfhashdkfj hsjdhf hdsfak jhdfa shdfajkhsdf adhf akdsjhfkajhd sfkjahsdkjf haksjdhfasdf adf
        dsfjadjkfhak sdhfkjashdfjk adhfa hdfh
      </div>
      <div class="page-detail-bottom">
        bottom bar
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm a bit unclear on when you'll need scrollbars. Without a set height, a div will always expand vertically to fit it's content, regardless of width.

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I have divs with fixed width and height on left, top, bottom and right (float) of the window. The div in center needs to occupy the remaining space, but if browser window is smaller than say 1000px, which forces the div to be say min-width:600px, I want scrollbars to show up on that div.

Comment: Have you heard of @media tags in your CSS? They are essentially rules that you can set based on window size. If you change your current center div to NOT have scrollbars, and then add this at the *end* of your CSS, it will give scrollbars only when the window is less than 1000px wide.

    `@media (max-width: 1000px) {`
      `.page-detail-left-main-content {`
          `overflow: scroll;`
       `}`
     `}`

Comment: Thanks Tyler! Will give that a try. Also, someone suggested "text-overflow: none;" and that worked too.

Comment: @J.Doe Sounds good! Media queries are good to know in general if you plan on making things change based on window size. It's how responsive websites are made, in case you need to shuffle/resize things when viewing on a phone, as compared to a tablet, or full-screen monitor, etc. Good luck! :)